# Problem with HTML form submit

Tags: php, html, forms

Can anyone tell me why this form does not properly submit values to server?

```
  <form method="post" action="http://www.***.com/index.php/session/authenticate" class="form login" id="login_form"> 
    <div class="group wat-cf"> 
      <div class="left"> 
        <label class="label right">Login</label> 
      </div> 
      <div class="right"> 
        <input type="text" class="text_field" id="username"/> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="group wat-cf"> 
      <div class="left"> 
        <label class="label right">Password</label> 
      </div> 
      <div class="right"> 
        <input type="password" class="text_field" id="password"/> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="group navform wat-cf"> 
      <div class="right"> 
        <button class="button" type="submit"> 
          <img src="images/icons/key.png" alt="Save" /> Login
        </button> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </form>
```

On the server side I echo out the `$_POST` superglobal which is empty, and I can see my request headers which are sent when the form is submitted:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:ci_session=***session_id=***user_agent%22%3Bs%3A50%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Macintosh%3B+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_6_7%29+App%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1307578661%3B%7D31ee24db2875550081268dc7df883f76; ci_csrf_token=***
Host:www.***.com
Origin:http://**.com
Referer:http://***.com/index.php/session/login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/*** Safari/534.30
```

Comment: Does the HTML validate? Could there be two nested forms?

Comment: sure about that action url ??

Comment: Do you var_dump $_POST or $_POST['']? Because that looks correct. Also, you should use var_dump or print_r as the $_POST is an array

Comment: I'm just commenting out the action url for security purposes, the actual form has the proper action url which is confirmed by the output from my php script on the server

Comment: insecure to give us the url of a site on the internet, there must be a lot of insure sits out there then :-)

Comment: it's a test with no mysql string escaping

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot to give the name for the input type, like this

```
<input type="text" class="text_field" name="username" id="username"/> 

<input type="password" class="text_field" name="password" id="password"/>
```

Comment: I thought using 'name' was deprecated in favor of 'id'?

Comment: No, they are both used. Name is for the server (the actual name of the field), id is used for CSS. The ID is not sent to the server

Comment: name is not deprecated for form elements.

Comment: `name` is only deprecated for most elements outside of form elements, and on `form` itself. It is _not_ deprecated for `input` elements and the like.

Answer (score 1):

You `input` tags have no `name` attribute. I think you are using `id`'s instead of `name`'s

For instance

```
<input type="text" class="text_field" id="username"/>
```

should be

```
<input type="text" class="text_field" id="username" name="username" />
```

or simply

```
<input type="text" class="text_field" name="username"/>
```

if you are not using the `id`'s for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It's the name attribute of input elements that's submitted on the form.  Use name='username', etc.